# Организовать связь 3 таблиц Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, activerecord

Есть 3 таблицы

- `User('id', 'username', 'password')`
- `Books('id', title, user_id)`
- `Sales(id, book_id, id_client, id_seller, cost)`

`id_client` и `id_seller` - должны быть из таблицы User. Вот я написал такой "бред" в модели.

```
class Sales extends ActiveRecord{
    public function getBooks(){
        return $this->hasOne(Books::className(), ['id' => 'book_id']);
}
public function getUser(){
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), [
        'id'=> 'id_client',
        'id'=> 'id_seller',
         ]);
}
```

И вот значит я получаю список покупок

```
$sales = Sales::find()->joinWith('books')->joinWith('user')->all();
```

И вот вроде все отлично работает, но имя пользователя возвращается только одно. Что тут лучше сделать ?

Comment: Воспользуйтесь gii

Answer (score 1):

```
class Sales extends ActiveRecord
{
    public function getBook() {
        return $this->hasOne(Books::className(), ['id' => 'book_id']);
    }

    public function getClient() {
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'id_client']);
    }

    public function getSeller() {
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'id_seller']);
    }
}
```

Получаем:

```
$sales = Sales::find()->with('book, client, seller')->all();
foreach ($sales as $sale) {
    $book = $sale->book;
    $clientUser = $sale->client;
    $sellerUser = $sale->seller;
}
```